# How to switch style sheets dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi I have a page  for which I have four different style sheets like this

```
      <link rel="Stylesheet" href="fancydropdown.css"  title="style-1" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="Alternate" href="fancydropdown_1.css" title="style-2" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="Alternate" href="fancydropdown_2.css" title="style-3" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="Alternate" href="fancydropdown_3.css" title="style-4" type="text/css" />
```

And this is my HTML

```
    <div id="menu">
    <ul class="tabs">
<li><h4><a href="#">In the blog &raquo;</a></h4></li>
<li class="hasmore"><a href="#"><span>Styles</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a   href="#" rel="style-1">style-1</a></li>
        <li><a   href="#"  rel="style-2">style-2</a></li>
        <li><a   href="#" rel="style-3">style-3</a></li>
        <li><a   href="#" rel="style-4">style-4</a></li>            
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="hasmore"><a href="#"><span>Topics</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>   
<li><h4><a href="#">Elsewhere &raquo;</a></h4></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
<li class="hasmore"><a href="#"><span>Networks</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">posterous</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SpeakerSite</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">See more&hellip;</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Bookmarks</span></a></li>
```

this my dropdown class

```
     <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a   href="#" rel="style-1">style-1</a></li>
        <li><a   href="#"  rel="style-2">style-2</a></li>
        <li><a   href="#" rel="style-3">style-3</a></li>
        <li><a   href="#" rel="style-4">style-4</a></li>            
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
```

when I click on style-1 and so on the style sheets shoud be change .....How can I do this using jquery? Can any one help me?

And please provide me the library's to be used to?

Comment: a simple google search would be sufice.

Comment: i tried several examples but no luck..style sheets are not chnaging -@machineaddict

Comment: have you checked for any javascript errors? you should use firebug

Comment: anil kumar What's the reason for switching stylesheets? browser compatibility/ verson/ screen size? There are many simple alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change the HREF of your stylesheet.

```
... HEAD
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="style1.css" >

... BODY
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a data-stylesheet="style1.css">style 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-stylesheet="style2.css">style 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-stylesheet="style3.css">style 3</a></li>
</ul>

... SCRIPT
$('.dropdown a').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('link').attr('href',$(this).data('stylesheet'));
});
```

Comment: just make one stylesheet and change the href. the way you have setup the stylesheet is weird. I'll change my answer to show you the better way.

Comment: data-anything is valid in html5 which is the beauty of the data element

Answer (score 0):

Please try following which works fine. See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/fLzck/

```
<ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a   href="#" rel="style-1.css">style-1</a></li>
            <li><a   href="#"  rel="style-2.css">style-2</a></li>
            <li><a   href="#" rel="style-3.css">style-3</a></li>
            <li><a   href="#" rel="style-4.css">style-4</a></li>            
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu item 6</a></li>
        </ul>

$(".dropdown a").click(function() {
    var thisRel = $(this).attr('rel');
    //alert(thisRel);
    $("link[rel='stylesheet']").attr('href', thisRel);
})​
```